# GitHub API issue events assigned by

Tags: json, rest, github-api

I am using GitHub API to fetch issue events. I want to display **who** was assigned to the issue and **by who**.

As per [GitHub Api documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/) , `assigned` and `unassigned` events have one extra attribute for this particular feature, `assignee`, along with standard `actor` attribute:

> `assignee` : The User object which was assigned to (or unassigned from) this Issue. Only provided for 'assigned' and 'unassigned' events.
>
> `actor` : Always the User that generated the event.

Problem I have is that GitHub API returns the same person for `actor` and for `assignee` attributes.

*Example:*

User **mjohnson** assigns user **jdoe** to an issue.

Event describing this should have **jdoe** as `assignee`, and **mjohnson** as `actor`.
GitHub API returns **jdoe** in both, `assignee` and `actor` object.

*Question:*

Why is this happening and how to get **assigned by** user?​

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in the GitHub API. Did you contact support to report it?

Comment: I contacted GitHub support, this is a known issue which is still opened. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For "assigned" and "unassigned" events you should now see a new "assigner" attribute which tells you which user performed the action.

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#attributes

I hope this helps